# deleting a constraint in storyboard makes it gray (disabled) - I want to delete it

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I'm in my storyboard, and applied a constraint by control-dragging from one view to another, to replace another constraint that doesn't make sense anymore. So I select the view, go to the "Size Inpector", hit the old constraint, and then the delete key.

The annoying thing, is that it just clears the "Enabled" flag, and grays out the constraint.

And yes, I am using size-classes... but here's the thing, I don't have this constraint used on any other size classes. In fact, currently there are no variants of views, constraints, etc. Everything is on "Any / Any".

So, I'm wondering if there's a way to make the Delete key actually work here. Is my only recourse going to the Document Outline, and finding my constraint in there? It just seems like there should be a more simple way to ditch the constraint, but in the Size Inspector.

Comment: If you double-click the constraint in the size inspector it will select it in the document outline for you so you can delete it from there

Comment: Xcode version? It deletes for me...

Comment: @dan - if you put your answer in the "answer" area, I'll accept it and upvote it.

Comment: @CaptJak - Xcode 7.2.1. I think this would delete as expected if I didn't have Size Classes turned on my storyboard document. But with it on, it just disables.

Comment: It says in the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html), that "For constraints, you can change the constant for a constraint and you can change whether the constraint is installed in the view hierarchy."

Comment: I'm not talking about what can be done at runtime. I'm talking about editing the Storyboard in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using size classes what often happens is that when you delete a constraint, it merely removes it for that size class.

However, there is a clear visual hint given when you do this: **the constraint icon goes grey and is easily identifiable in the document outline**, from where it can be selected and removed completely.

I'm not sure whether this has changed over various versions of XCode, but I find when I select it in the inspector, it does not remove it unless you are on Any/Any.